# How to show all products of specific category in a cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have create one cms page in magento.i have also show one category products on that page.In that category 18 products. but in cms page showing only 12 products.

i have try following code.

```
 {{block  type="catalog/product_list" limit="18" category_id="383"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Maybe that category has 12 active products or quantity more than 0. Maybe after 12 its printing but due to some layout or div not showing.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan  In that category  18 active products.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet your value for the config option "Products per Page on Grid Default Value" is set to 12.

Go to Config -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Frontend and increase the value of "Products per Page on Grid Default Value" to 18 (or higher).